# Moment.js isSame() With Custom Format Won't Work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, momentjs

I can't get `isSame` function to work in Firefox when the custom date format is `MM-DD-YYYY` because of  firefox's hard coded format `2016-09-16T05:46:57.745Z`.

Is there away to make the `MM-DD-YYYY` with `isSame` in firefox? Not a issue in Chrome

```
jo = new moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY')
"09-16-2016"
mom
"09-16-2016"
moment(jo, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "09-16-2016", _f: "MM-DD-YYYY", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2016-09-16T05:00:00.000Z }
moment(jo, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isSame(mom)
false
moment(jo, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isSame(mom, 'day')
false
```

Comment: Somewhere in here, you are incorrectly parsing a date string and are getting a warning that says 'moment construction falls back to JS date'. Where is the variable mom defined? That's probably where this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if firefox is giving you the right timestamp using  `new Date()`

**Firefox's date**

[image: Firefox's Date]

**Chrome's date**

[image: Chrome's Data]

This could be the possible reason for the wrong validation.

Answer (score 0):

You `mom` variable is a string not in a *recognized ISO format* so the console will give you the following warning:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

Moment `isSame` will try to convert you `mom` string into moment object, but as [parsing docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) say:

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

As you can see in the linked table, strings in `MM-DD-YYYY` format are not supported in Firefox.

I suggest you to parse you `mom` string specifying format, so you will have something like:

```js
var jo = moment();
var mom = "09-16-2016";
// Parse string into moment object, specifying format
mom = moment(mom, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
var eq1 = moment(jo, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isSame(mom);
console.log(eq1); // false, different hours/minutes
var eq2 = moment(jo, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isSame(mom, 'day')
console.log(eq2); // true
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```